# why error is showing in iteration using map function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

could you please tell me why I am getting while iteration using map function in react ? I comment out my code so that you can see my code and provide me feedback where I am doing wrong

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/jzpr5o8x2v

```
function App() {
  console.log(a)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
     { a.map(([title,arr])=>{
       return (
          <li>{title}</li>
          // arr.map(({ displaytext})=>{
          //   <li>{displaytext}</li>
          // })
        )
      })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Expected output**

```
GENERAL
Mobile NUMBER 04061511
Abc NUMBER.  89999

Personal Info
Address.  g-78
local.   090099
```

This code is not working

```
 // arr.map(({ displaytext})=>{
          //   <li>{displaytext}</li>
          // })
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the `.map` callback (in your commented out code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the `a` properly and return the elements.

```
function App() {
  console.log(a);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {a.map((elem, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {elem[0]}
              <ul>
                {elem[1].map(nestedEle => {
                  return [
                    <li key={1}>{nestedEle.value}</li>,
                    <li key={2}>{nestedEle.type}</li>,
                    <li key={3}>{nestedEle.displaytext}</li>
                  ];
                })}
              </ul>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lr9j1x1v2m

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here:

- When returning a JSX value from a function, the return value must have a single root. You have the `<li>` side-by-side with the inner `map`. If you don't want to wrap everything with a new element, you can use `<> ... </>` to wrap everything.
- When mixing JSX with code expressions, you need to place `{ }` around the code.
- You're not returning anything in the callback of the inner `map`.

This produces the described result:

```
{ a.map(([title,arr])=>{
  return (
    <>
     <li>{title}</li>
     { arr.map(({ displaytext})=> <li>{displaytext}</li>) }
    </>
  )
})}
```